# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine: Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Actually I configured one Android project in android studio, this project was originally created by my colleague in his machine (Windows-7, 64-bit, jdk 1.8), my machine also has same configuration (i.e. Windows-7, 64-bit, jdk 1.8) but if I tried to run this project, it gives me the above error at run time. Please see the below screen shot for more information--

[image]

Solutions I tried so far are---

```
1]  try to add something like this to your gradle.properties file in the project:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

2] Changed below file to modify vm heap option.
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
I increased -Xms128m to -Xms512m and restarted Android Studio.

3] Tried creating a new environment variable named _JAVA_OPTIONS, set it to
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m.

4] File -> Settings -> Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)
Change the "**VM options**" to
-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

 5] go to environment variables
    in system variables add :
    New Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
    New Variable Value: -Xmx512M
    Restart Android studio
**but in this case didn't found any "VM options" option in Compiler option**
```

But none of above solutions worked for me, so any help will be really appreciated. Also let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any explanation but uninstalling existing jdk and reinstalling fresh jdk solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed below file to modify vm heap option.

C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions

I increased -Xms128m to -Xms512m and restarted Android Studio.

Comment: IF NOT WORK Delete .gradle folder from c:\users\{username}\.gradle

Comment: CLEAN REBUILD RUN

Comment: Already tried this solution but didn't worked for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: UDATE YOUR GRADLE CURRENT 2.10